# %ALL namespace is not appearing in available namespace list

Tags: intersystems-iris

I have created %ALL namespace to map with two existing namespaces to use class globally but I am not able to select %ALL namespace as it is not appearing in the available namespace list. How to create objects in %ALL namespace?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

%ALL is just a virtual namespace.
It has no related data or global store.
You only see it in SMP in namespace mappings.
And there you can also list it